# Computer freezes, CPU fails, solution?

Tags: cpu, freeze

Computer freezes, CPU fails, solution?

I recently have this problem. My computer HP dc7700 SFF freezes randomly.
I keep this computer on all the time for running a teamspeak server (very light use). 
The computer freezes randomly, usualy when I'm not using it for a while (I use another computer for general use) The computer will just freeze, the screen stops, can't move the mouse, numlock on keyboard has no response. There's no event log on computer management. I have no idea what's going on.

I open the case and find that the cpu heatsink is cold. The fan of the CPU and PSU are working and don't seem to be overheat, I can eject the DVD-drive's tray. The screen stop, if it freezes for a long time, it will just have black screen. I can force shut down and start and work again.

So does can anyone know what's the problem? CPU failing? anything I can do to fix it?  any help is appreciated :)

The computer's spec:
Core2Duo 1.86Ghz
128mb ATI x600
3GB DDR2 Ram
2X 2TB drives, 
DVD-burner

Comment: Have you run memory diagnostics?

Comment: The fact the heatsink is `cold` tells me the CPU is being turned off.

Comment: Will do Ram test tonight. Yeah if the CPU is fired, I won't be able to turn the pc back on right?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like bad memory. If you have two sticks in there already, use trial and error to figure out which one, if any, is bad. As an alternative, run memtest86+.

Comment: will do it now.

Comment: tested for 2 hours with no error. any more suggestion?

Comment: Update your graphics/audio/network drivers?

Comment: I tested the ram for more than 11 hours with no error. Some update: i tried the HWInfo ( http://www.hwinfo.com/ ) and the log showed that the CPU voltage and temperature were fine. The computer just stopped and crashed. Screen are stopped, cant move the mouse and thing like that. The CPU was cold, all the fans are moving. I can still use the computer after i restart it. The crashes are pretty random sometimes after one day, sometimes after 2 or more days. 
anyone have any idea? I can upload the log if needed.

Comment: It could be a bad PSU or bad motherboard too. Before that, verify that it's not the processor by running Prime95, IntenBurnTest/Linpack, or another similar stress-testing program. Be warned, make sure you monitor your CPU temps closely when using these tools.

Comment: the HWInfo log showed the temps is ok... the pc just gone while i was watching a movie last night

Comment: Your PC gone what? You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like bad ELECTROLYTIC CAPACITOR problem...
You should open your computer and visually inspect ALL capacitors. First place to look is around memory slots. Consult Wikipedia, and similar sources about ELECTROLYTIC CAPACITORS. When BAD they are SWOLLEN, and sometimes they LEAK on TOP, or BOTTOM.

Comment: The answer doesn't get better with liberal use of CAPS.

Comment: sometimes even a general purpose CAPS can help :-)))